# Use _trackPageview on email click or submit form

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics

Hi I want to know how much is email clicked or form submited. But I dont see anything in analytics. Thank you for advice.

```
<script>
  $('form').submit(function(){
    _gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/ContactUs.stub']);
  });

  $('a[href^="mailto"]').on('click', function() {
    _gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/Email.stub']);
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Check if you are using the correct version - this is "classic" GA code, won't work if you are using the current version of Google Analytics (and if your account is younger than three years or thereabouts you are most likely using Universal Analytics).

Answer (score 0):

That code are from old GA code ('GA classsic'). If didn't works, you would use Universal Analytics code  :

```
<script>
  $('form').submit(function(){
    ga('send', 'pageview', '/ContactUs.stub');
  });

  $('a[href^="mailto"]').on('click', function() {
    ga('send', 'pageview', '/Email.stub');
  });
</script>
```